# Can I inject dependencies into objects not created by the DI framework

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, objectify

How can I inject dependencies into objects that weren't created by a DI framework?

I am running an application on Google App Engine using Objectify, so POJOs are created by Objectify when data is fetched from the datastore. Personally i like having convenience methods to get related objects, like car.getOwner().getName() The car object is created by Objectify. The code of getOwner() owner would be something like

```
public Person getOwner(){
    return PersonService.getById(this.ownerId);
}
```

I could improve it with a ServiceLocator

```
public Person getOwner(){
    return ServiceLocator.getService(PersonService.class).getById(this.ownerId);
}
```

But how would I do this with DI?

I looked at Guice, but i can only think of putting the Injector in a singleton and access it from the getOwner method.

Is my thinking flawed?

Comment: Not answering directly, but having datastore operations hidden behind innocent-looking getters will backfire at you sooner or later. The client code expects to be able to call the getter at any rate with no performance issues. For example, in a GUI view a repaint listener may call it tens of times per second while a component is being moved around. There are many other scenarios.

Comment: I am writing a web application and there are several levels of cache. This approach makes lazy loading data from within templates really easy. Which is why I like it. I have worked with methods like this for years. Testing them is a pain, though. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik this is how most ORM works. Hibernate does exactly the same (even more innocent-looking cause the implementation is actually in the proxy).

Comment: @Pache Yes, Hibernate is another example of the same. I have dug myself into a hole once with it and have also read horror stories from many other users here on SO. Since that incident I have used Hibernate in a totally different way: not as a smart persistent state manager, but as a thin layer over the SQL queries. My life has been bliss ever since and performance is stellar.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik interesting. While I did not encounter such issue, I can believe how painful it could be. Also this is not the first time I hear about your approach with hibernate. Definitely worth a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Objectify4 you can subclass ObjectifyFactory and override the construct() method.  This will allow you to inject your entity classes.

You can see an example here:  https://github.com/stickfigure/motomapia/blob/master/java/com/motomapia/OfyFactory.java

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of is load time weaving, [I quote](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/aspectj-ltw-spring-config.html):

> The context:load-time-weaver registers AspectJ's Load-time Weaver to
>   the current classloader. So, not only Spring beans will be targeted,
>   but any class loaded in the classloader that match the defined
>   pointcuts.

But I think that will conflict with the GAE restrictions but I haven't tried this in GAE yet.